# Free groups as HNN-extensions

Tags: geometric-group-theory

Let $G$ be the free group with two generators, say $a$ and $b$.
Then the Cayley of $G$ with respect with the generating set is 4 regular tree.
If we contract every edge with the label $b$, then we end up with a tree $T$ such that $G$ acts on the edges of $T$ transitively.

Applying Bass-Serre theory implies that $G$ is the free product $\langle a\rangle $ and $\langle b\rangle $.

My question is the following:

How can I modify the Cayley graph of $G$ in order to get an HNN-exentension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the tree that you have described *is already* an HNN extension tree, because its quotient graph of groups is a graph with one vertex and one edge. The vertex is labelled with the cyclic group $\langle b \rangle$, and the edge is labelled with the trivial group $E$.

The group element $a$ is the stable letter of that quotient edge, leading to the HNN presentation
$$F_2 = \langle a,b \mid aea^{-1}=e \rangle
$$
where $e$ is the identity element of $\langle b \rangle$.

Although there are other seemingly less trivial HNN extensions of $F_2$ that can be described, and although this may seem like a somewhat trivial example of an HNN extension, it is nonetheless an example.

Comment: Thanks, another question can be raised here: Can every infinite group split over $\mathbb Z$? My observation: Every manifolds contains a closed curve.

Comment: That's a nice question. However, instead of burying that question in a comment of an answer of your last question ---- where it will be essentially invisible to the community --- you should instead ask it in a new question where the whole community will see it.